# Проигрывание видео в div

Tags: html, видео, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли реализовать такую функцию, которая бы продолжала воспроизводить видео на том месте, на котором ты обновил страницу, то есть запомнить время видео и при обновлении страницы продолжать его проигрывать?

Есть много плагинов для воспроизведения видео через бэкграунд, но нигде нет функции продолжения воспроизведения после обновления страницы. Сам пользуюсь Jquery.VideoBG, видео находится в div'e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто перед обновлением страницы занести в локальное хранилище текущее время видео.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("lasttime")) //Проверяем, есть ли в хранилище сохранённое время
   localStorage.setItem("lasttime", "0") //Если нету, то заносим в хранилище время 0
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  this.currentTime = localStorage.getItem("lasttime");//устанавливаем время видео из хранилища
}, false);

window.onbeforeunload = function(event){   //детектим когда человек обновляет страницу   localStorage.setItem("lasttime",document.getElementById('vid1').currentTime) //перед тем, как обновится страница, заносим текущее время видео в хранилище
};
```

Попробовать [тут!](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYbbLm?editors=101)

Comment: Решил отказаться от плагина VideoBG, т.к он особой роли не играет в моей идее. Ваш код отлично работает, у меня тоже самое, но продолжать воспроизведение не хочет никак.

код html: 

<video id="vid1" autoplay loop>
    <source src="bombsight.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' /> 
</video>

Код от js ваш. Без понятия..

Comment: Хмм, на codepen.io почему-то все работает прекрасно и у меня. Получается проблема у меня, вот только не пойму, из-за чего скрипт не хочет работать.

Comment: @unnamed что в консоли, есть ошибки?

Comment: @unnamed я имел ввиду в браузере в консоли!

Comment: Да, есть одна:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @unnamed странно, но у меня всё отлично работает, может, это как-то повлияет http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MYaKyg?editors=101

И попробуйте еще обернуть всё в `window.onload = function(){ //код}`, вероятно, он не может найти элемент.

Comment: Вы на локалхосте пробовали? У меня только там не работает, а на сайте все отлично. Вообщем, спасибо большое за код, это то, что мне нужно! :)

Comment: @unnamed "Спасибо" не нажмёт галочку напротив ответа)))